# LINQ optional where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've used this example:
[Linq with optional WHERE options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931048/linq-with-optional-where-options/32931287)
...to make optional where clause on my LINQ, but the problem is i allways get null  result for user.
isverified is a bool value and it's true if master password is correct, in that case i don't need linq part (w.Password == model.Password)

when isVerified is true i need my linq to look like:

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == model.Username);
```

I tried something like this:

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == model.Username && (!isverified || w.Password == model.Password));
```

or

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == model.Username && (isverified || w.Password == model.Password));
```

Comment: I believe your isverified expression is inverted.  
&& (isVerified || w.Password == model.Password

Comment: I worry this code implies a plain-text password

Comment: That's a *bad* example that can easily result in bad execution plans. If you don't want a `where` clause simply don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should invert `isverified` condition:

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == model.Username && (isverified || w.Password == model.Password));
```

But it generates not optimal query plans in sql server.

So, prefered way - create dynamic query:

```
var users = _context.Users.Where(w => w.Name == model.Username);

if (!isverified)
{
    users = users.Where(w=>w.Password == model.Password);
}

var user = users.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Only the *second* option is good. The first one can result in bad execution plans like all catch-all queries. Both queries are dynamic anyway